# Debian package postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 suddenly stopped installing

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgis

Literally overnight, the postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 package stopped successfully installing on Debian 7.6. I am not seeing much online and the postgresql IRC seems to be unaware of the issue.

The error I recieve:

```
root@debian:/home/vagrant# apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: liblwgeom-2.1.4 (>= 2.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: postgis but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installation steps:

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

Anyone else experiencing this error? Looks like liblwgeom was updated this morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get past the issue on my debian wheezy by doing this:

```
sh -c 'echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
apt-get update
apt-get install libjson-c2
apt-get install liblwgeom-2.1.4
apt-get install -y postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have problems with apt.postgresql.org, please use the mailing list: pgsql-pkg-debian@postgresql.org

We are now rebuilding postgis on wheezy with backports disabled.

Comment: I did write to that mailing list and received a very nice message from a Marcus this morning. He reiterated the same answer given by LR1234567 above.